# Swift round elements of a matrix

Tags: swift, cgaffinetransform

I have a CGAffineTransform M and I wish to round each element of the matrix like:

```
 M.a = round(M.a),
 M.b = round(M.b),
 ...
 ...
```

Is there an easy way to do this in one line?

Comment: Sure: `M.a = round(M.a); M.b = round(M.b); ...` – all in one line :)

Comment: Actually I wonder what you need this for.

Comment: The reason is I do not want 0.999 or -0.001 in the matrix elements. The only valid entries in my matrix are 0, 1, -1. This is set as a transform metadata of video track in Quicktime file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you want to do round your matrix elements, or if it's a good idea. But anyway, there's nothing in the SDK that lets you do it “in one line”.

You could add an accessor in an extension that makes it easy:

```
import CoreGraphics

extension CGAffineTransform {
    var elements: [CGFloat] {
        get { return [a, b, c, d, tx, ty] }
        set(n) { (a, b, c, d, tx, ty) = (n[0], n[1], n[2], n[3], n[4], n[5]) }
    }
}

extension CGAffineTransform {
    mutating func round() {
        elements = elements.map({ $0.rounded() })
    }
}
```

Comment: I would prefer to write `map` for `CGAffineTransform`, rather than jumping through Array to do it. I suspect most graphics code is performance sensitive, you wouldn't want to be allocating temporary arrays like this.